# .NET Timer array problem

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, timer

I've created an array of timers and initiated all of them and everything was fine but in debug mode I found that if I start one timer in array and then another one, the previous timer stops. How should I keep more timers running?I though of dynamic structure but I don't like it :D

I'm using `Windows.Forms.Timer`

In class I'm declaring

```
Timer[] timeSchedule = new Timer[0];
```

And Initiating them with this. It takes size of array from listview and intervals from string I created while loading listview. I hope you will find it understandable.

```
private void TimerRefresh()
{
    string[] TempArray = new string[lvSchedule.Items.Count];
    timeIntervals = new int[lvSchedule.Items.Count];
    TempArray = intervals.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));            
    for (int i = 0; i < timeSchedule.Count(); i++)
    {
        timeSchedule[i] = new Timer();                
        timeIntervals[i] = Convert.ToInt32(TempArray[i]);
        if (timeIntervals[i] == 0)
        {
            timeSchedule[i].Interval = 23;
        }
        else
        {
            timeSchedule[i].Interval = timeIntervals[i];
            timeSchedule[i].Tag = lvSchedule.Items[i].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm runing it with simple

```
timeSchedule[lvSchedule.SelectedItems[0].Index].Start();
```

Comment: please post some source code.

Comment: There are several types of timer in .net. Please elaborate and post some code.

Comment: Unfornutately I have no connection at home. So i had to post it from one of my friends but i you just wait I'll go get it :)

Comment: I don't know what you're doing there, but it sounds wrong. Maybe you want to use [a real scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: what is in the timer tick method code?

Comment: Timer tick is not assigned yet but it will call other method that don't mess with timeSchedule at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the timer tick function, re-enable the timer if you want it to fire again after the set interval. Post the timer tick code

Comment: Even if they're synchronous, that doesn't mean that one stops ticking if another one is activated.

Comment: @Bobby true.. lets wait for some code. may be something wrong with his object references.

Comment: I've put all timers in array under watch and if I start one timer, other timer stops, there is no way to start more than one timer so recursion have no use for me

Comment: Are you sure the timer tick method is running long enough to do this test?

Comment: There must be a misunderstand. It has nothing to do with timer tick. Problem I want to solve is turning off one timer when other starts(It happens without any code written by myself)

Comment: So once again, if I start a timer from array it runs without problems, but if I start another one timer from array, the other(running one) stops

Answer (score 0):

1. If you start a timer, the other timer will not just stop unless you stop it either by calling its `Stop()` function or changing its `Enable` to false.
2. In the code you provided you don't assign the timer `Tick` event handler on any of the timer, so assign them in the loop `timeSchedule[i].Tick += OnTimerTick`..
3. Use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) or [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instead of the current `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` because:

   a. The [Timer.Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) handler will executed on the UI thread, which will cause the UI to be not responding while the code in the tick is executing.

   b. `System.Windows.Form.Timer` has a lower *accuracy* `limited to accuracy of 55 milliseconds` and you are using `23` in your code, however that does not mean it will be exact `23` when using `System.Timers.Timer` but it have a better resolution..

Comment: On a non-realtime-OS nothing will have this kind of precision. You can bet that whatever you do, it will be off by 10 to 25 ms.

Comment: @Bobby: Actually if you use multimedia timer and set the its resolution to `1` you will get about `1ms`. to set the resolution: `timeBeginPeriod(1);` and `timeEndPeriod(1);` to return to the normal behavior. i.e about `15ms` in xp

Comment: @Bobby: well I test it my self at `Windows XP` and `Windows Server 2003` and it get around `1ms`.

Comment: @Bobby: note that I said to him `however that does not mean it will be exact 23 when using System.Timers.Timer but it have a better resolution`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every answer here I already solved the problem...It was all my fault :( I didn't realize what I was doing when I put inicialization of this array in Form Activated triger however...it's now solved. by the way...thanks for advice with this timer accuracy...(I'm using 23ms too recoglize if this tmer is to me started or not, however, I'll remeber it and some day I'll find it helpful as everything from here :) )